# Changing display properties of a layer using ArcGIS Server REST API Export Map function

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I have a quick question I hope someone can help with.

Using the ArcGIS Server (10) REST API's [Export Map function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/export.html) can I specify the boundary type, colour, fill colour and other properties in the features that are in the image?

I know I can easily do this if I use client-side rendering in Flex or Silverlight, and I have previously done this server-side in WMS with SLD, but so far I haven't seen this in a map image retrieved from the REST API.

There is some documentation on the Export Map function but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Any info would be much appreciated.

Comment: I recall hearing something like this might be coming at 10.1.

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall thanks for the hint, looks like this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a post](http://blogs.esri.com/dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/04/26/considerations-for-arcgis-server-developers_3a00_-a-look-toward-10.1.aspx) (see **Changing symbols and renderers**) from the ArcGIS Server Blog mentioning that sort of functionality coming for 10.1.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I got all excited to read that yes, this functionality will be supported. Then I googled the release date for 10.1 - early 2012. Now my options are 1) wait or 2) use ArcObjects. I think I'll wait.